# How to Store 2 Shorts and a float inside a double?

Tags: c

I happen to have a embedded program that requires me to do some bit operations to store alot more information.

I have 2 shorts and a float as such. I need to store it into a double (64 bit), and then retreive all that info without loss in precision from that double. I can only use C99 valid operations and am not even able to do bit shifting on double.

```
short x = 4012; short y=1234; float s = 0.8;
double store = 0;
```

Unfortunately, I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Do you have `uint64_t`?  It will be less troublesome to pack these quantities into a `uint64_t` than a `double` (for instance, NaNs are not an issue).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a union:

```
union Foo {
  struct {
    short x;
    short y;
    float s;
  } ssf;
  double dbl;
};

int main() {
  union Foo v;
  v.ssf.x = 4012;
  v.ssf.y = 1234;
  v.ssf.s = 0.8f;

  // read a double
  double store = v.dbl;

  // set the double value
  v.dbl = store;

  // read the float back out
  printf("%f\n", v.ssf.s);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Setting a member of a union (`v.ssf` and its members) and reading another (`v.dbl`) gives undefined behaviour.   Reading the same members that have been set is fine.

Comment: Unless `double` has trap representation(s) it should be fairly safe, and if the size of each member is the same it should even be safe to extract the double from one union, use that value to set it in another, and get the same values for the union other field. You could conceivably use memcpy to set only the necessary bits of a double, but if there are trap representations you have the same problem. In practice, the only worry is that the struct will be padded or short and float aren't 16 and 32 bit respectively.

Comment: @Peter: C++ forbids that, but [C tries to explicitly allow it](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#note82). (IIRC, there are issues with how it tries to allow it, but it tries.)

Comment: That said, this is likely to give wrong results when the double value becomes a NaN, or even trap for signalling NaNs.

Comment: Given OP's constraints I don't think anything can be done about trap representations. If you want to use the same memory to store doubles and ints it's going to be possible to end up with problem values. As for NaNs, AFAIK it's safe to copy around a NaN and assume you'll end up with a bit-exact copy which you can then plug back into the union, but I'm not sure if the C standard guarantees it or if it's just that implementing it another way in hardware is just nonsensical.

Comment: @user2357112 - yes, C tries - essentially, type punning.   Which requires quite a few constraints on the types, which aren't satisfied with your approach.    Getting a trap or NaN representation are not the only potential concerns.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your shorts and float in a stuct, it will *literally* be 2 shorts and a float in continuous memory. Same exact memory footprint. But you wont have to fiddle bits to access and modify the individual variables.  Probably, using a struct will actually *save* memory, because you wont need intermediary variables to put in the CPU registers when interacting with your shorts and float.  Furthermore, you'll about a whole slew of potential bugs in your bit fiddling code.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to nemequ's answer, the internal `struct` can be anonymous to avoid needless typing:

```
union Foo {
  struct {
    short a;
    short b;
    float c;
  };
  double d;
};

int main() {
   union Foo foo;
   foo.a = 12;
   foo.c = 2.3f;
}
```

Comment: It's definitely a style issue, but I usually try to avoid anonymous members in a union. That extra typing helps make it clear which values are discrete; for example, with your version it's not clear that setting `foo.a` will preserve `foo.b`, but setting `foo.d` will not. I'd **much** rather type a few extra characters in favor of making the code easier to understand when reading it.

Comment: To preserve the *style* and readability, clearing documenting the use of the union will help avoid any confusion while preserving the anonymous struct use.

Comment: Documentation is great, but it's not a substitute for a good, unsurprising API. The API should do as much as possible to help people avoid mistakes even if they don't read the documentation in full. Sometimes that means being a bit more verbose, sometimes choosing good names, other times adding annotations to help improve compiler warnings.